# javax.jcr.version.VersionException: Cannot set property. Node is checked in

Tags: aem

I am trying to upload an image in DAM and workflow (OOTB) gets stuck. following is the error I am getting.

```
12.07.2018 09:58:27.712 *ERROR* [JobHandler: /etc/workflow/instances/server1/2018-07-11_2/update_asset_923:/content/../../../../../../icon-1.png/jcr:content/renditions/original] com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.AssetImpl addRendition: cannot add new rendition [cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png] for asset [/content/dam/____________________________]: 
com.adobe.granite.asset.api.AssetException: javax.jcr.version.VersionException: Cannot set property. Node is checked in.
    at com.adobe.granite.asset.core.impl.DefaultRenditionHandler.setRendition(DefaultRenditionHandler.java:79)
    at com.adobe.granite.asset.core.impl.AssetImpl.setRendition(AssetImpl.java:131)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.AssetImpl.addRendition(AssetImpl.java:490)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.AssetImpl.addRendition(AssetImpl.java:484)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.RenditionMakerImpl$PlanBasedTemplate.apply(RenditionMakerImpl.java:129)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.RenditionMakerImpl.generateRenditions(RenditionMakerImpl.java:184)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.process.CreateThumbnailProcess.execute(CreateThumbnailProcess.java:121)
    at com.day.cq.workflow.compatibility.CQWorkflowProcessRunner.execute(CQWorkflowProcessRunner.java:93)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:215)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:143)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.startJob(JobQueueImpl.java:395)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.access$100(JobQueueImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl$1.run(JobQueueImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jcr.version.VersionException: Cannot set property. Node is checked in.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.checkPreconditions(NodeImpl.java:1330)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.prePerform(SessionDelegate.java:606)
```

After image upload I can see the property set on the asset node is

[image]

What can be the possible cause of this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known product bug affecting AEM 6.0, 6.1 and 6.2.

From [official documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/experience-manager/kb/versionexception-after-author-edits-a-page.html)

> This is a known product bug CQ-4215298.  When a user creates a version
>   or publishes ("activates") a page that is locked by another user, then
>   it causes the page to go into an inconsistent state.

Resolution

> This issue is fixed in AEM6.3 and AEM6.2 SP1 Cumulative Fix Pack 8.
>
> With or without the fix pack applied, you would have to fix the broken
>   pages.  To fix the pages, follow the steps below:
>
> Go to /crx/explorer/index.jsp and log in as admin user. Open Content
>   Explorer. Browse to the jcr: content subnode of the broken page.  For
>   example: /content/geometrixx/en/services/jcr:content Go to Versions =>
>   CheckOut. Go to /sites.html UI and browse to the page and open it for
>   editing. Unlock the page by clicking the lock icon on the top left.